# How can i create multiple types of java objects using a single JSON file with the help of jackson mapper?

Tags: java, object, hashmap, jackson, geojson

I want to create multiple types of java objects using a single JSON file

I have thought of storing different types of java objects in the form of map where key will be the name of object type and value will be the Object itself as shown below

Field2_AllIn1.json

```
 {
 "fetchMapOfStringType": {

        "hi": "hello"

    },

    "fetchMapFieldType": {

        "5b0b8a5545424a20487ee2bc": {
            "fieldId": "5b0b8a5545424a20487ee2bc",

            "value": "25",
            "values": [],
            "visible": true,
            "fieldValidationErrors": [],
            "globalValidationErrors": [

                {
                    "fieldValidationId": "5b0b8a5545424a20487ee2bc",
                    "validationErrorMessage": "this is error"

                }
            ],
            "formulaErrors": []
        }

    }


 }
```

first one stores a simple String type 
second one stores a java object of type  map where Field is a custom class

```
public class JsonJacksonAllInOne {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{



        try {



            // read JSON from a file
            Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(
                    new File("C://json/Field2_AllIn1.json"), 
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });

            //type String
            //String type works fine
            Object obj1 = map.get("fetchMapOfStringType");
             Map<String, String> mapStringType  =  (Map<String, String>) obj1;
            System.out.println(mapStringType.get("hi"));//this prints hello


             //second type ... type casting to object type to objectId and Field map 
             Map<ObjectId, Field> map1 = (Map<ObjectId, Field>) map.get("fetchMapFieldType");

             ObjectId k1 = new ObjectId("5b0b8a5545424a20487ee2bc");
             Field f1 = map1.get(k1);
             //this code gives value of f1 as null


             // this gives class cast exception 
             // java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.dto.Field

                Field f2 =  map1.get("5b0b8a5545424a20487ee2bc");


        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

as you can see the comments in the code .
one gives null 
other gives class cast exception 
I guess the casting is not working 
how can  I get the objects of required type 
Is there any other way where in I can use a single JSON file to create different java objects such as maps and list of custom classes ? ?
I want to avoid using different JSON files for creating different java objects

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with this line:

```
// read JSON from a file
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(
                    new File("C://json/Field2_AllIn1.json"), 
                    new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
            });
```

When you read json as a Map, it will parse whole json as a LinkedHashMap (to store order as well, otherwise HashMap could also be used).
After that you can't cast it to another POJOs / Beans.

Solution is to read json as a tree, and then convert directly into your POJOs when needed to avoid unnecessary type casting, here is updated code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // read JSON from a file as a tree
        JsonNode map = mapper.readTree(new File("/home/pratapi.patel/config.json"));

        // fetch json node from the tree
        JsonNode obj1 = map.get("fetchMapOfStringType");

        // convert obj1 (JsonNode) as Map<String, String>
        Map<String, String> mapStringType =
                mapper.readValue(mapper.treeAsTokens(obj1), new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
                });

        // prints hello
        System.out.println(mapStringType.get("hi"));

        // fetch another json node from the tree
        JsonNode map1 =  map.get("fetchMapFieldType");

        // convert map1 (JsonNode) as Map<ObjectId, Field>
        Map<ObjectId, Field> mapFieldType = mapper.readValue(mapper.treeAsTokens(map1), new TypeReference<Map<ObjectId, Field>>() {
        });

        ObjectId k1 = new ObjectId("5b0b8a5545424a20487ee2bc");
        Field f1 = mapFieldType.get(k1);

        System.out.println(f1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also Since ObjectId is used as a key in Map, it should be final and equals / hashCode should be overridden to work it properly.

```
public class ObjectId {

    private final String value;

    @JsonCreator
    public ObjectId(@JsonProperty("value") String value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Auto generated in eclipse
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Auto generated in eclipse
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ObjectId other = (ObjectId) obj;
        if (value == null) {
            if (other.value != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This has saved hours . Thank you.